# Always show negative values on Y axis using D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have a dataset which is is something like

```
[{key: 'abc', series: [1000,2500,3000]}, {key: 'xyz', series: [-20, 0,0]}]
```

In this case when I plot my bar chart with d3.js, The 'y' label ticks ignores negative values since they are not in the range of other numbers (1000,2500,3000). Is there a way to force the negative number ticks to be shown. Or if my y tick range is [0,200,400,800] then it should be [-200, 0, 200,400,800].

Comment: You need to show a bit more code here.  How are you defining your scales and axis?

Answer (score -1):

You may hard code your y axis range using:
    `d3.scale.linear().range([-200,800]);`